# Remove loop partitions created by Anbox snap app?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, snap, anbox

I was trying to install Anbox snap app on Xubuntu 16.04.1 but it failed to install. Now there are three loop device partitions viz loop0, loop1, loop2 created while installing. I have uninstalled Anbox but these loop partitions are not deleted. How to delete these partitions without breaking the system. Is it safe to delete these partitions using **Gparted** or **Disks** application?

Comment: I'm guessing you removed Anbox with `sudo snap remove anbox-installer`?

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled using this command.

Comment: I made a thread on the snapcraft forum [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/loop-partitions-not-removed-when-a-snap-is-removed/2519) but didn't get much attention :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ogra* posted a solution on [snapcraft.io](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/loop-partitions-not-removed-when-a-snap-is-removed/2519). By removing snap (using command `sudo apt purge snapd`) from Xubuntu system the loop partitions will be deleted automatically. This means there is no longer I can use snap apps on my system. Apparently I dont use any snap-apps so this will work for now.